# Custom variables for devise user saving, but not appearing in console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I used Devise to set up a routine user module, but then I wanted to add more variables to it and am having trouble.  I followed [this tutorial](http://jacopretorius.net/2014/03/adding-custom-fields-to-your-devise-user-model-in-rails-4.html) and made the following changes:

My `routes` line for `devise` now reads:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }
```

My `registrations_controller` is:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  private

  def sign_up_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :role, :gender, :dob, :age, :goal_weight, :goal_muscle, :goal_bodyimage, :goal_performance, :goal_endurance, :goal_health, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end

  def account_update_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :role, :gender, :dob, :age, :goal_weight, :goal_muscle, :goal_bodyimage, :goal_performance, :goal_endurance, :goal_health, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
  end
end
```

And I added the fields to my `new` and `edit` views in the style of the others.

Here's my `new` form:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div class="field text-left">
    <%= f.label :first_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :first_name, autofocus: true, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field text-left">
    <%= f.label :last_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :last_name, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field text-left">
    <%= f.label :gender %><br />
    <%= f.select :gender, options_for_select([['Prefer Not to Say', 'Prefer Not to Say'],['Female', 'Female'],['Male', 'Male']]), {}, {class: "form-control"} %>
  </div>

  <div class="field text-left">
    <%= f.label :dob %><br />
    <%= f.date_field :dob, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field text-left">
    <%= f.label "What are your goals?" %><br />
    <p><%= f.check_box :goal_weight, value: "1", checked: false, options: {} %> Lose Weight<br>
    <%= f.check_box :goal_muscle, value: "1", checked: false, options: {} %> Gain Muscle<br>
    <%= f.check_box :goal_bodyimage, value: "1", checked: false, options: {} %> Better Overall Body Composition<br>
    <%= f.check_box :goal_performance, value: "1", checked: false, options: {} %> Increase Sports Performance<br>
    <%= f.check_box :goal_endurance, value: "1", checked: false, options: {} %> Gain Endurance<br>
    <%= f.check_box :goal_health, value: "1", checked: false, options: {} %> Better Health</p>
  </div>

  <div class="field text-left">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field text-left">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
    <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
    <% end %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field text-left">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off", class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And here's my `edit` form:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :first_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :first_name, autofocus: true, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :last_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :last_name, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :gender %><br />
    <%= f.select :gender, options_for_select([['Prefer Not to Say', 'Prefer Not to Say'],['Female', 'Female'],['Male', 'Male']]), {}, {class: "form-control"} %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :dob %><br />
    <%= f.date_field :dob, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "What are your goals?" %><br />
    <p><%= f.check_box :goal_weight, value: "1", checked: false, options: {} %> Lose Weight<br>
    <%= f.check_box :goal_muscle, value: "1", checked: false, options: {} %> Gain Muscle<br>
    <%= f.check_box :goal_bodyimage, value: "1", checked: false, options: {} %> Better Overall Body Composition<br>
    <%= f.check_box :goal_performance, value: "1", checked: false, options: {} %> Increase Sports Performance<br>
    <%= f.check_box :goal_endurance, value: "1", checked: false, options: {} %> Gain Endurance<br>
    <%= f.check_box :goal_health, value: "1", checked: false, options: {} %> Better Health</p>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, class: "form-control", autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <% if devise_mapping.confirmable? && resource.pending_reconfirmation? %>
    <div>Currently waiting confirmation for: <%= resource.unconfirmed_email %></div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %> <i>(leave blank if you don't want to change it)</i><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, class: "form-control", autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: "form-control", autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :current_password %> <i>(we need your current password to confirm your changes)</i><br />
    <%= f.password_field :current_password, class: "form-control", autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Update My Info", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

All forms render correctly.  When I hit `submit` or `update` I get a flash notice that the information has saved successfully.

When I save information I get something like this in the server that shows that the new information, including the checkbox values, is being saved:

```
Started PUT "/users" for ::1 at 2016-06-03 17:17:42 -0700
Processing by RegistrationsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"DomUJ8aFghDIOPYsWQPlB7KnmFt27ZDcPOf7SdG4PWvI8QgI3OZP5mscbVfpGtlNpIZKTIqhL+RRwj1/3VT9AQ==", "user"=>{"first_name"=>"Test", "last_name"=>"Testerson", "gender"=>"Prefer Not to Say", "dob"=>"2008-08-08", "goal_weight"=>"0", "goal_muscle"=>"1", "goal_bodyimage"=>"0", "goal_performance"=>"1", "goal_endurance"=>"0", "goal_health"=>"0", "email"=>"test@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "current_password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Update My Info"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.4ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "goal_weight" = ?, "goal_performance" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "users"."id" = ?  [["goal_weight", 0], ["goal_performance", 1], ["updated_at", "2016-06-04 00:17:43.005855"], ["id", 2]]
   (0.6ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 148ms (ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)
```

Here's where the trouble starts.  When I go back to my `edit` page after that, all of the new variables are displayed in their fields EXCEPT the checkboxes (no matter how many/few were previously checked:

[image: Sample edit form, after new variables have saved]

Then, when I check for the user in my console, NONE of the new variables are displayed:

```
irb(main):007:0> User.second
  User Load (7.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
=> #<User id: 2, email: "test@gmail.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$11$y9/F8GQ9sTUK7Hm.b81Eo.VEbvvZ93XdOdZivAgQxhB...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 1, current_sign_in_at: "2016-06-04 00:04:34", last_sign_in_at: "2016-06-04 00:04:34", current_sign_in_ip: "::1", last_sign_in_ip: "::1", created_at: "2016-06-04 00:04:34", updated_at: "2016-06-04 00:17:43">
```

On the other hand, I **CAN** call them up other places using erb like `<%= @user.first_name %>`.

Can anyone help me figure this out so all of the new variables save?

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Here is the migration that added the new variables to the `user` model:

```
class FlushOutUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :full_name, :string
    add_column :users, :first_name, :string
    add_column :users, :last_name, :string
    add_column :users, :role, :string
    add_column :users, :gender, :string
    add_column :users, :dob, :date
    add_column :users, :age, :integer
    add_column :users, :goal_weight, :integer
    add_column :users, :goal_muscle, :integer
    add_column :users, :goal_bodyimage, :integer
    add_column :users, :goal_performance, :integer
    add_column :users, :goal_endurance, :integer
    add_column :users, :goal_health, :integer
  end
end
```

Comment: Type `User` and `> User.second.first_name` in the console - what do you get in each case? Also, how do you 'go back to your edit page'? Do you get redirected, or are you typing the address of the edit page in the address bar, or hitting browser back button?

Comment: `User` gives me `User(id: integer, email: string, encrypted_password: string, reset_password_token: string, reset_password_sent_at: datetime, remember_created_at: datetime, sign_in_count: integer, current_sign_in_at: datetime, last_sign_in_at: datetime, current_sign_in_ip: string, last_sign_in_ip: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)`

Comment: `User.second.first_name` gives me `User Load (10.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
=> "Test"`

Comment: Have you added/edited and run migrations to add these custom fields to the users table? Can you share the migration file?

Comment: @Anand, yes, I've done all the appropriate migrations to the database, and the migration file is (or shortly will be) added above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove checked: false from all the checkboxes. This should fix the checkbox issue. For example:

```
<%= f.check_box :goal_weight, value: "1", options: {} %> Lose Weight<br>
```

Update: The users table does have the custom field columns - as you mentioned in your comment (but did not mention in the question console output), there is an ellipsis (`...`) at the end of the user in the console output. This means that there are more fields.

Comment: This fixes some of the problem.  When changed they maintain their value when you leave and re-enter the edit page.

Comment: However, when I put `User.second` into the console the new variables still don't appear:
`  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
=> #<User id: 2, email: "test@gmail.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$11$y9/F8GQ9sTUK7Hm.b81Eo.VEbvvZ93XdOdZivAgQxhB...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 1, current_sign_in_at: "2016-06-04 00:04:34", last_sign_in_at: "2016-06-04 00:04:34", current_sign_in_ip: "::1", last_sign_in_ip: "::1", created_at: "2016-06-04 00:04:34", updated_at:...">`